# mysql - multiple rows of COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

For example I have a data here

```
ID    Doctor    Status
1     Wooka     Approved
2     Jamba     Approved
3     Jamba     Approved
4     Wooka     Approved
5     Wooka     Approved
6     Wooka     Approved
7     Wooka     Approved
.    .          .
.    .          .
.    .          .
99
```

For the first 7 rows (demonstration purposes, not limited to 7) I want it to output like this

```
Doctor    Count
Wooka     5
Jamba     2
```

Although I am not sure how to do that in COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE status='Approved'
```

I really don't have any idea how to make it flexible as to what I've asked.

Comment: Look up how to GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `limit` clause in a subquery to limit the number of rows returned, and then wrap this query with an aggregate query that performs a `count`:

```
SELECT   doctor, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT   doctor
          FROM     mytable
          WHERE    status = 'Approved'
          ORDER BY id ASC
          LIMIT    7 -- or some other number
         ) t
GROUP BY doctor
```

Comment: @Noobster yes. That's what the `group by` clause is there for

Comment: Hello, yes this works. But im wondering how if to map all the status? Like Approved, Pending, Denied, ...the list goes on and on?

Comment: @Noobster If you want a count per status, drop the inner `where` clause and add the status to the `group by` clause.

Comment: @Noobster yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  t.doctor,
  COUNT(*) AS c
FROM
  table t
WHERE
  t.status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY
  t.doctor
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the "first 7 rows" requirement.